How to send trx without web wallet (via code)?
I need to send assets without a web wallet (I have to sign tx in the code).
I have publicAddress, secret key, passphrase and endpoint in QuickNode.
My code:
async createAssetTransaction(receiver: string, amount: number, assetCode: string, assetIssuer: string) {
let _receiver = "GAGN5YWP6EGHGBFD2O7FVHCXCVE5V2I6BFUJUCHRCFIC7RCAQIX4QTUX"
let _amount = 1
let _assetCode = this.stellarConfigService.assetCode
let _assetIssuer = this.stellarConfigService.assetIssuer

const account = await this.stellarServer.getAccount(this.stellarConfigService.walletPublicKey)

const asset = new Asset(_assetCode, _assetIssuer)

let transaction = new TransactionBuilder(account, {
  networkPassphrase: this.stellarConfigService.walletSecretKey,
  fee: "100000"
})

transaction.addOperation(
  Operation.payment({
    destination: _receiver,
    amount: _amount.toString(),
    asset: asset,
  }),
);
let buildTransaction = transaction.setTimeout(10).build() }


After building the transaction you need to sign it:
let keypair = StellarSdk.Keypair.fromSecret("YOUR SECRET KEY");
buildTransaction.sign(keypair);

And finally submit it to the network:
let horizon = new StellarSdk.Server('https://horizon.stellar.org');
horizon.submitTransaction(buildTransaction)

